# Start a Zoom meeting from the command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, shortcuts, zoom-meeting

I attend several recurring Zoom meetings every day and would like to streamline the process of joining them.

Is there a way to launch a Zoom meeting (with password) from the command line in Windows?

Comment: as the password is in the join link, you could use a powershell script to open a new browser window, retain the process ID, open the zoom link in it and then close the process of the opened window...just an idea - didn't test it as I am off shift now on my Mac now.

Comment: or [see here a python script idea](https://waynewerner.com/blog/launch-zoom-from-the-command-line.html)

Comment: Is there any way to specify the user name to use for this meeting in the Windows link or on the command line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Piece of cake!  Use a windows shortcut instead!  It's *easier* and *cleaner*.

***You can use this same method on Linux (or mac) but you will need to put it into a script or alias it instead.***

I figured this out myself when I went down the same path.

1. Create a shortcut to your zoom exe.  It should be in `%APPDATA%\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe`
2. Open the shortcut properties and edit the "Target" field.
3. Go down after the EXE and add (with the quotes) `"--url=zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<your_conference_number>"`

***If you have a password***, it is hashed so you will need to launch the meeting once in the browser and copy it out.  Once you have your hashed password, add `&pwd=<hashed_password>` after your conference number (with no spaces).

***Some other handy things to know***

- I myself add .LNK to my PATHEXT environment variable.  This allows me to launch a shortcut without clicking on it.  Possible vulnerability but I am willing to risk it.
- After adding that, I can put shortcuts in my path and launch them using only the name via the run dialog or console.

***An example***

- I put a shortcut for my standup meeting in my path.
- [Win]+r (pulls up the run dialog)
- I type 'standup' and hit [ENTER] to open my standup meeting.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: This is great but on Ubuntu it doesn't work when Zoom is already running.  In that case the command does nothing. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Answering my own question, the solution was to use `/bin/xdg-open zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=MEETING_ID`.

Comment: Where are you getting the syntax and the command line options from?

Comment: @Christoph .. to be honest, I can't remember where I got the first "bread crumb" that got me started.  I do remember wasting half a day in a debugger figuring this out.. sorry I can't give you more.

Comment: The password does not have to be hashed tho.  Might have changed since the answer but right now on linux I use the url with Zoom or xdg-open with  '...confno=###########&pwd=#######' and this works.  Being an URL, I should work on Windows as well.

Comment: None of the answers work for me on Linux currently. At best they’ll open an(other) instance of Zoom.

Answer (score 16):

If you're on a Mac you can join a zoom meeting from the command line like so (e.g. for conference ID 1234):

```
open "zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=1234"
```

To make it handier you can add a shell function to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
function  zoom () { open "zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=$1" }
```

Then you can just join a call using:

```
zoom 1234
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding the detail from @Thenujan Sandramohan's answer that the password parameter also works:
`open "zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=12345678&pwd=RANDOMnonsense"`

Comment: … In addition, the parameter `&uname=Your+Name+(she%2Fher)` supports setting your username for the call. Moreover, you're not limited to Alphanumerics if you escape properly as shown.

Answer (score 7):

> Go down after the EXE and add (with the quotes) "--url=zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<your_conference_number>"

This isn't work any more.
The correct is:

```
--url="zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<your_conference_number>"
```

So "--url=" must be **outside** the quotes!

Answer (score 7):

For linux users this method will not open a web browser it will directly open zoom app with meeting.

```
xdg-open "zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<conference_number>"
```

this will require you to enter password

if you have an invite link for zoom meeting
and it looks like the one below
"https://us05web.zoom.us/j/9332773648?pwd=OUFPQlIreVpONGX4VURkWjVxNzFFZz09"

you can modify the command above to the one below and it wouldn't require you to enter a passcode

```
xdg-open "zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=9332773648&pwd=OUFPQlIreVpONGX4VURkWjVxNzFFZz09"
```

Comment: How is this better than other answer?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Toto methods in the other answer will open a web browser and this one wouldn't

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thx!

Answer (score 3):

If you are Windows User you can write

```
start "url"
```

In the place of url you can put  your zoom link and join it easily

For Mac-OS

```
open "url"
```

For Linux

```
xdg-open "url"
```

this is the easy and quick way
But remember to that it will open the browser and browser will pop up and msg saying "Lunch Meeting In Zoom App" which leads to the opening of zoom app. So if you tick always open with app .
You are ready to go.

[Launch Meeting -Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smyl7.png)

Answer (score 2):

I like your answer [@Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/users/1000631/se%C3%B1or-cmasmas), but instead of a shortcut I'm using a scheduled task to start zoom.exe and using the --url as the arguments, as many of my meetings are recurring. So I want them to automatically pop them up for me, as time is always slipping by when I'm not paying attention.

Comment: Wow!  What a great idea!  It wouldn't work for me as I dodge as many meetings as possible. I wouldn't want my 2:00pm PoC meeting popping up over pointless youtube cat videos.    :^P

Answer (score 2):

For Mac Users:

Zoom may have changed something since these answers were posted. I was unable to get any of the formats for opening a password-locked room open on osX -- hashed, unhashed, using the --url scheme -- zoom would open but not go to the room.

The answer for me was to open the fully password hashed url in Chrome from the command line:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" https://zoom.us/j/[ROOM NUMBER]?pwd=[HASHED PASSWORD]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple Bash script on Linux to launch Zoom links.  I run this from my at queue so that meetings just pop up on schedule without touching my browser.

The essential part is that the script parses out three fields from a typical Zoom link:  The host, the meeting ID, and the hashed password.  Then I just run zoom with the option of a Zoom meeting URL of the format "zoommtg://[host]/join?action=join&confno=[meeting id]&pwd=[password hash]"

The script does a little extra to make sure my DISPLAY is set (in case I'm running this from something like the 'at' queue) and to verify that the URL is in the expected format with a regular expression match.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "${DISPLAY}" ] && export DISPLAY=:0

# Check for zoom meeting links
if [[ "$1" =~ https://[^/]*[.]zoom[.][^/]*/j/[0-9]*[?]pwd= ]]; then
    H="${1#*//}"
    H="${H%/*}"
    H="${H,,}"
    P="${1#*?pwd=}"
    M="${1#*/j/}"
    M="${M%?pwd=*}"
    # echo "H: '${H}' M: '${M}' P: '${P}'"
    (zoom "zoommtg://${H}/join?action=join&confno=${M}&pwd=${P}" &)
    shift
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    exit 0
    fi
fi

echo Unexpected arguments: "$@"
exit 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

##### Answer

`confno` and `pwd` are the values to set in the zoom scheme (URL).

I created a basic Python module to use for that:

```python
from os import startfile
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def meeting(number, password):
  url = 'zoommtg://zoom.us/join?'
  parameters = {
    'confno': number,
    'pwd': password
  }
  command = url + urlencode(parameters)

  # print(url + urlencode(parameters))

  startfile(command)
```

```python
from zoom import meeting

meeting (
  'NUMBER',
  'PASSWORD'
)
```

###### Gist:

- https://gist.github.com/rwp0/d618db33b989c08502817c8b92cd9014

Comment: Hello, please don't ask questions in your answer. Ask a separate question instead.

Comment: OK, it wasn't actually real questions, more of a just further thoughts concerning the topic :-)

Comment: Anyway asked a separate question as you suggested: https://superuser.com/questions/1786118/how-to-start-zoom-with-muted-from-cli