# Recognise link with password in zoom desktop client

Tags: zoom-meeting

How can I directly use a zoom link that includes the password with the zoom desktop client on mac OSX?

For meetings people usually sent me links which are structured like this

```
 https://zoom.us/j/<some long number>?pwd=<some hash of password>
```

(I don't get the meeting id/pin, only the link)

If I use the zoom desktop client to join the meeting, it will ask me to enter the meeting id. I can use the link instead, but in the next step it will ask me for the pin. So I have to go back to another application, copy the `<some hash of password>` part of the link and paste it there. Can this step be simplified?

I also tried to paste the link in my browser instead, but then I have to first cancel the download of the zoom installer (even though it is already installed) before I can click on join the meeting with desktop client. This at least will directly take me to the meeting without having to enter the password separately.

I tried from the command line with `zoommtg:`, as suggested in superuser.com/questions/1563255, but this needs urls like `zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<your_conference_number>`, while I have `https://zoom.us/j/<some long number>?pwd=<some hash of password>`. With this other url scheme zoommtg only opens the desktop client, but does not join the meeting.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1563255/start-a-zoom-meeting-from-the-command-line/1563359#1563359

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the link, but the `zoommtg:` trick needs urls like `zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<your_conference_number>`, while I have `https://zoom.us/j/<some long number>?pwd=<some hash of password>`. With this other url scheme zoommtg only opens the desktop client, but does not join the meeting.