# Join zoom webinar from command line

Tags: zoom-meeting

I learned from https://superuser.com/a/1563359/1193261 that if I rearrange a zoom link from

```
 https://zoom.us/j/<some long number>?pwd=<some hash of password>
```

to

```
 open zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<some long number>&pwd=<some hash of password>
```

I can use this link to directly join the meeting with the desktop client from the command line.

This works fine with normal meeting, but for webinars this prompts me to create a new meeting instead of joining the webinar. How to use this for webinars?