# Is there a way to make the Zoom URL join link to always use the browser and stop prompting use of the Zoom app/software?

Tags: zoom-meeting

We are giving away Zoom URL join links for our users from our website.

And for some user-experience issue, we wish to keep our users from staying on their browsers.

We know that [Zoom join link will say the user can still join the meeting via the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfvBI.png), but is there a way to make this a default and stop prompting users to download and launch the Zoom app?

Is there some URL query parameters we can add to the Zoom URL join link for this?

> [image]

Comment: I don't think Zoom would let you .. since the browser method has its own limitation (you also then have to let the browser to have access to audio / mic / video / screen recording). Also Zoom client by default does not require admin right (as they install under the user's own AppData profile) - so even restricted PCs (or user with no admin right) can still download and use Zoom desktop App without issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Zoom join link typically looks like:

```
https://zoom.us/j/12345678901?pwd=meeting_password
```

While there's no explicit way to join a Zoom meeting via browser as a default, you *could* craft a link leading directly to the Zoom web chat.

Take the meeting ID out of the URL above (the `12345678901`), and put it into the following link like so:

```
https://zoom.us/wc/join/12345678901
```

This link will take the user directly to the meeting `123 4567 8901` in the browser.

And then, if the meetings are password-protected, you can provide the password separately somewhere else on the website (I don't think it is possible to specify the password in the query string of a web-chat link, but I'm happy to be corrected on that)

Comment: Nice answer!  Perhaps [my post](https://superuser.com/questions/1563255/start-a-zoom-meeting-from-the-command-line/1563359#1563359) and your post might be able to combine to answer the password part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this chrome Extension does exactly that.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/conferfly-extension/mdkfiaghmngifghdafgglpfoimheoggb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).