# How to start Zoom muted from CLI

Tags: command-line, url, zoom-meeting

We have `--url` option to `zoom` (or `zoom.exe`) binary to start a meeting from the command line providing the meeting ID (`confno`) and meeting password (`pwd`) parameters as explained here:

[Start a Zoom meeting from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1563255/start-a-zoom-meeting-from-the-command-line/1786083)

What about other options, are their any?

I'd like to start my meeting with microphone muted using a CLI parameter, but I couldn't find options documentation for Zoom unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I tired multiple options but we can't disable audio and enable video in URL schema
Refer: https://devforum.zoom.us/t/opening-zoom-app-with-video-enabled-using-xdg-open-command-in-ubuntu-terminal-with-zoommtg-link/89165