# Command line sign in to Zoom in Win10

Tags: zoom-meeting

By copying the link in Zoom I'm able to apply a command in a batch file to open Zoom, however, Zoom requires me to sign in (in order to reinstate my status as host). Is there a batch command I can use to automate the sign in? I'm using Windows 10 and latest Zoom software.

Comment: https://github.com/tmonfre/zoom-cli

Comment: Did you see [this discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/1563255/start-a-zoom-meeting-from-the-command-line) down below the accepted answer?